# How do you printf and sprintf in Io?

Tags: string, printing, io, format

How can I:

- convert an object to a string without printing it, a la Python's str(obj)?
- print using percent (%) directives a la C's printf(format, obj1, obj2, ...)?
- create a string using percent (%) directives without printing to stdout a la C's sprintf(str, fmt, obj1, obj2, ...)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interpolation:

```
"2 + 2 = #{4}" interpolate
```

Concatenation:

```
"2 + 2 = " .. 4 asString
```

Interpolation with printing:

```
"2 + 2 = #{4}" interpolate println
```

Concatenation with printing:

```
("2 + 2 = " .. 4 asString) println
```